# Remove the Compass interfence alert message+Augmented Reality in iphone

Tags: iphone, augmented-reality, compass-geolocation

I am working on the application in which i had implemented Augmented Reality from [Git hub](https://github.com/mixare/mixare-iphone).
I am getting one alert view Written As:-

Compass Interference
Move Away from any interference or re-calibration by waving iphone in figure 8 Motion

How to i remove this alert
 please any one help me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. That warning is telling the user how to fix the fact that the compass is returning entirely worthless data. If your app can use worthless data, replace the use of compass information with a random number generator, and increase the number of iDevices you can run on. If it can't, then let the warning hang around so the user can fix the problem.

For a less glib answer, use `dismissHeadingCalibrationDisplay` on `CLLocationManager` and `- (BOOL)locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration:(CLLocationManager *)manager` on your `CLLocationManagerDelegate` instance.